# How to get the value of Input type number inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with several rows in which one of the cells has an imput type = number. I want to go through all the rows and get the number that is in that cell. I'm really lost on how to do it.

```
<tr class="iterate">
  <td class="cantidad"> <input type="number" 
onchange="actualizar()" name="cantidad" placeholder="0" min="0" max="99"></td>
</tr>   


function actualizar(){
  var total=0;
  $("tr.iterate").each(function() {
    var quantity1 = $(this).find(".cantidad").innerHTML,
    alert(quantity1);
  });
}
```

I tried with innerHTML, value, text() and with none of them working.

Comment: The selector `".cantidad"` will not work in this instance because the `.` denotes that you are looking for a class name, not an attribute's name. Add a better selector to the attribute (name or id) or use an attribute selector like `input[name$="cantidad"]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`.cantidad` is the `td` element not the *input* you are looking for. You have to find the input inside the `.cantidad`.

Also I will prefer `oninput` event instead of `onchange`:

```
$(this).find(".cantidad input").val()
```

```js
function actualizar(){
  var total=0;
  $("tr.iterate").each(function() {
    var quantity1 = $(this).find(".cantidad input").val();
    alert(quantity1);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="iterate">
    <td class="cantidad"> <input type="number" 
  oninput="actualizar()" name="cantidad" placeholder="0" min="0" max="99"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Please Note:** `innerHTML` and `value` used when using vaniall JS, you can not use them on jQuery referenced element.

Comment: @AdrielIdeidani, you can accept the answer by *clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in*.